# Scrolling through movie clip inside mask

Tags: image, flash, scroll, mask, movieclip

I am using Flash CS5 and trying to make a movie clip scrollable inside a rectangle mask.
I have tried different codes but it doesn't seem to assume the movieclip as the scrollable area and the rectangle as the mask.

I'm very new to this, there is probably an obvious solution.
Please help!

Comment: Are you using a scrollPane component? or trying to do this manually? What exactly have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

The link http://www.kirupa.com/developer/flash8/scrollbar.htm has a tutorial for scroll movieclip. I thing this tutorial will help you.